# Simple SQL statement combining two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm fairly new to SQL, and have the following problem. Consider these tables 'Cars' and 'Colors':

```
[Cars]
CarID   | Brand | ColorID   | Amount
1       | Ford  | 10        | 23
2       | VW    | 11        | 15
3       | Opel  | 11        | 12
4       | Opel  | NULL      | 21
5       | Ford  | NULL      | 16

[Colors]
ColorID | ColorName 
10      | Blue
11      | Red
12      | White
13      | Green
```

I want to have a query that lists all Cars with their ColorNames, so that I have this output:

```
CarID   | Brand | ColorName | Amount
1       | Ford  | Blue      | 23
2       | VW    | Red       | 15
3       | Opel  | Red       | 12
4       | Opel  | NULL      | 21
5       | Ford  | NULL      | 16

SELECT CarID, Brand, ColorName, Amount 
FROM Cars, Colors 
WHERE Cars.ColorID = Colors.ColorID
```

leaves out the records where ColorName = NULL.

```
SELECT CarID, Brand, ColorName, Amount 
FROM Cars, Colors 
WHERE Cars.ColorID = Colors.ColorID OR 
      Cars.ColorId IS NULL
```

yields too many records.

What SQL statement do I need here? I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

Thanks,
Cooz

Comment: Please use Join syntax to be ANSI-92 standard , instead of using commas

Comment: Never mind... I am not allowed to delete this question - but please don't bother answering it. This is rather basic SQL of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USE `LEFT JOIN`

Like this:

```
SELECT ca.CarID, ca.Brand, cl.ColorName, ca.Amount 
FROM Cars AS ca
LEFT JOIN Colors AS cl
ON ca.ColorId = cl.ColorId
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
CarID   Brand   ColorName   Amount
1       Ford    Blue        23
2       VW      Red         15
3       Opel    Red         12
4       Opel    (null)      21
5       Ford    (null)      16
```

Link to the demo:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/28f27/1

**EXPLANATION:**

`LEFT JOIN` Works like this

[image]

General Syntax:

```
SELECT column-names
  FROM table-name1 LEFT JOIN table-name2 
    ON column-name1 = column-name2
 WHERE condition
```

For More info follow the below links:

> https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp
>
> http://www.dofactory.com/sql/left-outer-join

Answer (score 0):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

You are looking for a `LEFT JOIN`, so the right syntax is:

```
SELECT ca.CarID, ca.Brand, co.ColorName, ca.Amount
FROM Cars ca LEFT JOIN
     Colors co
     ON ca.ColorID = co.ColorID;
```

Note:  You should also learn to use table aliases and qualified column names.  Whenever your query refers to more than one table, you should qualify all column names.

Answer (score 0):

Use left join. This will select all `colorid's` from second table and will return null values for the cars that does not have data in `colours` table

```
Select  CarID   , Brand , ColorName,   Amount
from cars 
Left join colors 
on cars.colorid = colors.colorid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cr.CarID, cr.Brand, cl.ColorName, cr.Amount FROM Cars AS cr
LEFT JOIN colors AS cl ON cr.ColorId = cl.ColorId and 
cl.colorId is not null
```

try this buddy